# Difference between using interface//type and supplying multiple type annotation when implementing overload in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, overloading

Say if i want to do function overload, i can simply do this:

```js
function foo(a: number): number
function foo(a: string): string
function foo(a: any) {
  return a
}
```

However, i could implement using interface or type as well:

```js
interface Foo {
  (a: number): number
  (a: string): string
}

const foo: Foo = (a: any) => {
  return a
}
```

So is there any difference when using these two ways? Seems like they both implement the functionality.

Comment: You're using the ordinary function in first case and the arrow function in the second one, is this intentional?

Comment: No difference in terms of types. Regular differences in terms of regular vs arrow function and const variable vs function